# On android onbackpressed event , how I can kill listview and activity to go back to the parent activity

Tags: android, android-layout

On clicking a button in activity, it open another activity and listview parallelly.
If I select record from listview then it populates in the fields of activity, but if i wont select any list item and press back button, the activity is blank which looks awkward.( the list disappears on pressing back button)

onBackPressed the list and activity both should disappear and I need to go the previous parent activity where it contains button .

How is it possible??

Comment: Please add the relevant code.

Comment: I don't know how did you get this, since you didn't provided your code, but if this list is consuming the `back` event, you can call the `onBackPressed()` of your activity in the `onBackPressed()` of the list or even in the `onDestroy()` method.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It seems you have a problem with your code. However, we can't help unless we have [code or information that can reproduce the problem](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Otherwise, we are just blindly guessing.

Comment: public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    this.finish();
}    This is onbackpressed event code.  I am calling the activity which has its layout and listview in oncreate itself. So onback pressed only list is disappearing but not the total activity